# How do you put your source code into Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am new to Kubernetes and so I'm wondering what are the best practices when it comes to putting your app's source code into container run in Kubernetes or similar environment?

My app is a PHP so I have PHP(fpm) and Nginx containers(running from Google Container Engine)

At first, I had git volume, but there was no way of changing app versions like this so I switched to emptyDir and having my source code in a zip archive in one of the images that would unzip it into this volume upon start and now I have the source code separate in both images via git with separate git directory so I have /app and /app-git.

This is good because I do not need to share or configure volumes(less resources and configuration), the app's layer is reused in both images so no impact on space and since it is git the "base" is built in so I can simply adjust my dockerfile command at the end and switch to different branch or tag easily.

I wanted to download an archive with the source code directly from repository by providing credentials as arguments during build process but that did not work because my repo, bitbucket, creates archives with last commit id appended to the directory so there was no way o knowing what unpacking the archive would result in, so I got stuck with git itself.

What are your ways of handling the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would use continuous delivery patterns, which means use Travis CI, Bitbucket pipelines or Jenkins to build the image on code change.

that is, every time your code changes, your automated build will get triggered and build a new Docker image, which will contain your source code. Then you can trigger a Deployment rolling update to update the Pods with the new image.

If you have dynamic content, you likely put this a persistent storage, which will be re-mounted on Pod update.

Comment: crystal clear tutorials on circleci (assuming you're on gce, as tagged in the question) https://circleci.com/docs/continuous-deployment-with-google-container-engine/ and https://circleci.com/docs/google-auth/

Answer (score 0):

What we've done traditionally with PHP is an overlay on runtime. Basically the container will have a volume mounted to it with deploy keys to your git repo. This will allow you to perform git pull operations.

The more buttoned up approach is to have custom, tagged images of your code extended from fpm or whatever image you're using. That way you would run version 1.3 of YourImage where YourImage would contain code version 1.3 of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to leverage continuous integration and continuous deployment. You can use Jenkins as CI/CD server, and create some jobs for building image, pushing image and deploying image.

I recommend putting your source code into docker image, instead of git repo. You can also extract configuration files from docker image. In kubernetes v1.2, it provides new feature 'ConfigMap', so we can put configuration files in ConfigMap. When running a pod, configuration files will be mounted automatically. It's very convenience.